# Nuclide debugger with node and babel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I've been trying to use Nuclide/Atom to launch and debug a unit test that uses Babel and ES6+ code. The launch config looks like this:

[image: Nuclide settings]

Node runs the unit test as if I had run it from the command-line, and does not stop at my breakpoints. If I use the same invocation at the command-line with --inspect-brk I can debug correctly (with sourcemaps) from the chrome-devtools url in Chrome. Is there a way to make this work? I can't really "attach" since the unit tests are, and should be, a straight-shot script execution.

Answer (score 2):

Nuclide currently does not support the new v8 Inspector protocol for debugging. You will need to use `--debug` flag to debug with Nuclide. Note, however, that the old debugger protocol has been removed from Node.js starting with Node.js 8.0.

PS. You can attach to a running Node.js process with Nuclide debugger just fine - just start your tests with `node --debug --debug-brk ...` and then attach the debugger from Nuclide. The test process will be stopped at first line, allowing you to resume execution at your own convenience.